# How to sign pdf file with just a certificate without private key in Java?

Tags: java, pdf, digital-signature, x509certificate

I get a certificate from some time stamping authority. I want know, if it is possible to sign the pdf document with just the certificate. All methods which I see is to sign with the certificate and private key in Java. If it is possible what class java can I use?

Comment: A *time stamping authority* provides *time stamps*, not certificates and keys to sign with. Did you mean "certificate authority"? Or do you actually want to time stamp instead of sign?

Comment: it is the TSA (Time Stamping Authority)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible.

Digital signature in a  public key infraestructure: The message is signed with private key and verified with public (the public key is included into the certificate)

But if you got a certificate from a certificate authority (CA), then you probably have the private key. A certificate is issued by the CA using a CSR (Certificate Signing Request) created by you and signed with your private key. See [Certificate enrollment process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37850134/certificate-enrollment-process)

Look for a `.key` file

---

**TSA vs CA**

A TSA issues "time stamps", not certificates. A CA issues certificates. Some of them can be used by a TSA to issue timestamp. To sign a PDF you need a private key and a certificate. To timestamp a PDF you need to request a timestamp to a TSA

Comment: Is not the CA, but TSA

Comment: Please, check my clarification about CA and TSA