# Using SHA512 but signature algorithm is SHA1 with spongycastle

Tags: java, android, csr, sha512, spongycastle

I am using the CsrHelper class from here:
[Certificate enrollment process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37850134/certificate-enrollment-process/49016837#49016837)

---

but my default_signature_algorithm is sha512withrsa. Although, when I put the csr in a file to analyse it using openssl's tool to analyze the csr: openssl req -in file.txt -noout -text

The subject, public key algorithm are all fine. The issue is in the signature algorithm where it is sha1withrsaencryption It should be sha512withrsa.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a config file somewhere to modify. I have java 1.8.0_144

Comment: Did you update that code to use SHA512withRSA? Show your changes please

Comment: Basically add `ALGOS.put("SHA512withRSA".toLowerCase(), new AlgorithmIdentifier(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("1.2.840.113549.1.1.13")));` and change the DEFAULT_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM